# Where is scala on node with spark-shell installed?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have Apache Spark installed on a cluster. I can run `spark-shell` on the cluster master node. So, it means there is the `scala` installed to this machine. However, I cannot start neither `sbt` nor `scalac`. Is it possible to obtain spark's scala and how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

No, Its not. You have to install manually. 
Go through these links.

https://www.scala-lang.org/download/

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html

Comment: Thank you (+1). Unfortunately, I am not a sudoer on this node.

Comment: Sudo permission is not require, you just extract .tar in a folder where you have permission. And set SCALA_HOME and PATH env variable in your bash file.